# Centralizar itens da RecyclerView com FlexboxLayoutManager

Tags: android

Estou usando FlexboxLayoutManager para alinhas os itens, porém, preciso que todos itens sejam alinhados no centro, independente da quantidade de itens (dinamicamente).

Quero que estes itens fiquem assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, o que fiz fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Quero que Ioiô fique no centro)

Como defini o layoutmanager:

```
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(this)
layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP)
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW)
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START)
layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.FLEX_START)

val adapter = TagAdapter(tags)
tagRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
tagRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

Tentei usar `layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.CENTER)` porém não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Não seria apenas isso não?

```
layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.CENTER)
```

ou

```
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(AlignItems.CENTER)
```

Fonte: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/demo-playground/src/main/java/com/google/android/flexbox/FlexItemEditFragment.kt

Comment: Já tentei, não funcionou